# different coloured text within a win form table/database depending on which button the user clicks

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[Here is a link to a picture of how the win form app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtpem.png)

I am making myself a to do list application in vb.net and i wanted to highlight urgent tasks somehow.  I thought maybe by changing the color of the text when a user clicks the urgent button.  Please see the picture above and here is my code for each of my buttons.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'check if text was entered
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'insert input into the database
    Me.TableTableAdapter.Insert(TextBox1.Text.Trim)
    ' Clear the contents of the text box to allow re-entry.
    TextBox1.Clear()

    'refil data
    Me.TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Table)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'check if text was entered
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'insert input 
    Me.TableTableAdapter.Insert(TextBox1.Text.Trim)

    ' Clear the contents of the text box to allow re-entry.
    TextBox1.Clear()

    'refil data
    Me.TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Table)


End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is??? How to make the text color change?? maybe the cell color change??

Comment: It only has an option to the change the overall text or cell colour.  I was thinking maybe there was a way to change the indivdual text colour via the code

Comment: Use the events of the DataGridView, something like that is usually handled in the formatting or drawing event.   Note that you will need to have some piece of data like a Status for each row to indicate which ones are Urgent, Late etc because some of the events fire over and over and over